# Prove or disprove $n^2 \log{n} = O(n^2)$

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I'm having troubles grasping Big-Oh notation and complexities. How do I go about either proving or disproving this statement?

Comment: If $n^2\log n\le Cn^2$ for large enough $n$, you would have $\log n\le C$ for all large $n$. Does there exist a $C$ for which this is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is not true, but assume to the contrary that $n^2\log n = O(n^2)$. Then there exist constants $C>0$ and $n_0>0$, such that $n^2\log n \leq Cn^2$ for all $n\geq n_0$.

Divide both sides of the inequality $n^2\log n \leq Cn^2$ by $n^2$ to obtain $\log n \leq C$, which hold for all $n\geq n_0$. This is a contradiction, since $\log n$ is not a bounded function, which the inequality says that it is.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$n=2^k$$
then,
$$(n^2)logn = (2^{k^2})log_2 2^k$$
$$= k(2^{k^2})$$

And 
$$n^2 = 2^{k^2}$$

You can clearly see that asymptotically,
$$k(2^{k^2})>2^{k^2}$$
$$\therefore (n^2)logn > n^2$$
That's why the given relation is false. But $(n^2)logn= \Omega (n^2)$ will hold true.

Comment: What's the point of the first 5 steps??

Comment: I have used a simple technique known as variable substitution.

Comment: After using variable substitution the comparing the growth of the functions becomes relatively easy.

Comment: The other answer shows you that those five steps are extraneous, and it's easy to get to the second last step directly. Of course I know it's substitution, but I'm saying that in this case it's not purposeful.

Comment: There are errors in that derivations, relative to how to work with powers $n=2^k \implies n^2=2^k \cdot 2^k=2^{k2}$.